# mysqli_query not working when called from inside a function

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = 'root';
$db_database    = 'drmahima_com';
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_query($link, "SET names UTF8");
function temp() {
    $patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name,dob FROM patients WHERE id='69'"));
    echo $patient['name'];
}
temp();
?>
```

When I run this, the query doesn't seem to execute and nothing shows up on the page. However, if I remove the function and just change the code to this:

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = 'root';
$db_database    = 'drmahima_com';
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_query($link, "SET names UTF8");
// function temp() {
    $patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name,dob FROM patients WHERE id='69'"));
    echo $patient['name'];
// }
// temp();
?>
```

It works, and the patient's name is displayed.

What is going on here?

Comment: its a scope issue. `$link` is out of scope, you'll need to pass the connection in the argument. `temp($link)`

Comment: Because of Scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php . If you still wanna use outside variable in function, you can declare `global $link;` inside function and you'll be good.

Comment: thanks! can't believe I'm so stupid

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$link` to the function. It is not working because of the `scope` of that variable. Try with -

```
function temp($link) {
    $patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name,dob FROM patients WHERE id='69'"));
    echo $patient['name'];
}
temp($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the $link to function as a parameter. Try this:

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = 'root';
$db_database    = 'drmahima_com';
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_query($link, "SET names UTF8");
function temp($link) {
    $patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name,dob FROM patients WHERE id='69'"));
    echo $patient['name'];
}
temp($link);
?>
```